# Radio button value for switch statement's expression

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, radio-button

I have two switch statements and I need a third statement to determine one of the two  to run. In the first statement(default) I have:

```
innerHTML = "<form><input id='rb1' type='radio' name='option1' value='1'>1<input type='radio' name='option1' value='2'>2<form>";
```

I'm trying to place the value in `var testNumber`

I've used `document.getelementByNames('option1').checked` and for some reason checked causes errors. iv also used  `document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;` and that causes errors also

```
function
switch (testNumber) {
  case 1:
    test1();
    break;
  case 2:
    test2();
    break;
  default:
    test1();
    break;
}

function test1() {
  let div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  div1.innerHTML = "<form><input id='rb1' type='radio' name='option1' value='1'>1<input type='radio' name='option1' value='2'>2<form>";
  testNumber = whatTest();
}
whatTest() {
  let option1 = document.getElementsByName(option1)
  for (let i = 0; i < option1.length; i++) {
    if (option1[i].checked) {
      return option1[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the use of option[i] just a typo?

Comment: There's no function `document.getelementByNames`, only `document.getelementsByNames`.

Comment: You can't have line breaks in a quoted string. If you want a multi-line string, use backticks.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `option1`? Is that supposed to be a quoted string?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Aes option[i] should be option1[i]. As far as I know, you can only use `document.getElementsByName` because there can be more than one name. I been told backticks don't work on all browsers. Option1 is the name of the radio inputs.